# Vimeo -- rate limits header X-RateLimit-Limit -- CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo-api

I am using the Vimeo API to get back a video, like so: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#/{video_id}

The data comes back, but I am unable to access the response headers that tell me the rate limits.

In the Network tab on Chrome devtools, I can see that they are listed under the Access-control-expose-headers, but I am unable to get to their values by using either jQuery jqXHR's

```
 jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders()
```

or

```
jqXHR.getResponseHeader('X-RateLimit-Limit')
```

calls. I even tried doing

```
jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-RateLimit-Limit')
```

but that returned null as well.

I am making a Cross-Origin request.

Any ideas on how to get the value of that header back?

Comment: Is the `X-RateLimit-Limit` header listed in `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` of the response? Unlikely that it is missing but...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Vimeo's API. Vimeo is aware of the issue and is in the process of resolving it.